# Serenity: Cannot find Target showing for 3 seconds

Tags: java, selenium, serenity-bdd

I'm trying to find a Target that is a snack-bar with a message and a button that is only visible for 3 seconds after I click on a button:

[image]

If I pause the debugger I do find the element with the css selector `.mat-snack-bar-container`:
[image]

But in the code when I try to get the Target with the same selector it is never found not as a Target nor if I use the driver to find the element:

```
actor.attemptsTo(WaitUntil.the(SnackBar.SNACK_BAR_CONTAINER,isCurrentlyVisible()).forNoMoreThan(10).seconds());
```

I've tried `isCurrentlyVisible`, `isVisible`, `isPresent` and nothing.

With findElement I also get nothing:

```
WebElement snackBar = webDriver.findElement((By.cssSelector(".mat-snack-bar-container")));
```

When I see the screenshots of the steps I do see the snack-bar...

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why the actor was not able to find the snack-bar. In the file `serenity.properties` I had this line: `serenity.step.delay=2500` which is just the time that this element was visible.
If I used the driver directly this was not affected and I could see the snack-bar both in the screenshots and in the pagesource. But using the actor I could only see it in the screenshots and sometimes.
Once I lowered the step delay to 500 I was able to find the element.

Thanks everyone for you help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make:

```java
WebElement snackBar = webDriver.findElement((By.cssSelector(".mat-snack-bar-container")));
```

```java
WebElement snackBar = webDriver.findElement((By.className(".mat-snack-bar-container")));
```

Comment: No. In `cssSelector` you can use the class name by denoting with `.`

Answer (score 0):

If you know what text will be presented then you can use `textToBePresentInElementLocated` method. Let's see below example,

**HTML**: I am assuming your HTML will be like this.

```
  <input class="mat-snack-bar-container"> Workflow testing "sth" saved. </input>
```

**Wait till text presents** if you know the expected text

```
  WebElement snackBar = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@class='mat-snack-bar-container']"), "Workflow testing"));
  snackBar.click();
```

Comment: Have you changed the tag name? `//*[@class='mat-snack-bar-container']` or `//snack-bar-container[@class='mat-snack-bar-container']`

Comment: This to me it doesn't work, it still does not find the element. The HTML is similar: <snack-bar-container class="mat-snack-bar-container"><span>Workflow testing "stg" saved</span></snack-bar-container> so updating the wait.until with textToBePresentInElementLocated("//simple-snack-bar/span"), "Workflow testing") it still doesn't find the element..

Comment: I noticed that when I print the html source with driver.getPageSource() I also don't find the text so it's impossible to find it with findElement... I'll do some more testing to find out why... Thank you very much @Nandan A